# Automatic broadcasting warning: How to compare matrix rows to vector in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm getting the warning:

> warning: mx_el_eq: automatic broadcasting operation applied

From the code:

```
f = [1;2;3];
f == 1:3;
warning: mx_el_eq: automatic broadcasting operation applied
```

Can this can be done without warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are comparing column vector `f` with row vector `1:3`. In Matlab this would be an error however Octave automatically broadcasts. This means that in order to apply the `==` operator it will expand one of your vectors along a singleton dimension (i.e. a dimension of size 1). In you case both vectors have a singleton dimension to expand so you essentially get the equivalent of:

```
a1 = [1  1  1;
      2  2  2;
      3  3  3];  %// for f

a2 = [1  2  3
      1  2  3
      1  2  3];  %// for 1:3

a1 == a2
```

Note that in order to get the same result in Matlab you would have to directly call `bsxfun`

```
bsxfun(@eq, f, 1:3)
```

In order to compare you vectors elementwise without the broadcasting you just need to transpose one of them:

```
f' == 1:3
```

Comment: @jay_phate no problem. If an answer solves your question then you should strongly consider [marking it as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You should consider this for your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic broadcasting was a new feature introduced in Octave 3.6. It surprised many people (which were expecting an error), so it was decided to throw a warning. To disable this warning you'll need to turn it off with:

```
warning ("off", "Octave:broadcast");
```

You can also turn it off only in the scope of your function:

```
warning ("off", "Octave:broadcast", "local");
```

However, I'd recommend you do it in your `.octaverc` file instead.

The problem with the decision of throwing a warning is that it sounds like you are doing something wrong when you're really not. So as of Octave 4.0, that warning got removed (it is now part of the "Octave:language-extension" warning id).